# Laravel - Using query function gives an error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to take `$max` results. But sometimes the `$max` is NULL, so the query must returns all results.

I use this code:

```
$results = MyModel::whereIn('player', $players)->take(function($query) use ($max) {
    if (isset($max)) {
        $query->take($max);
    }
})->get();
```

But i get this error:

```
[ErrorException]                                       
  Object of class Closure could not be converted to int
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. What you think it's an integer, it's really an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$query = MyModel::whereIn('player', $players);
if (!empty($max)) {
    $query->take($max);
}

$result = $query->get();
```